# Why does the shape differ when importing an SVG file?

Tags: objects

Consider:

[image]

I have made a sword shape in [CorelDraw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CorelDraw) and exported it in the [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) format. The shape when imported in Blender looks compressed. The original image attached with the Blend file is:

[image]

Why is it compressed?

You can get the SVG file from https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwiTD4qoMzsZWmxSMjZFSzVzQWM.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/zeffii/a50863b18bd6fcb0b574dbf232c9cc44

Answer (score 5):

To increase the resolution of the Curve Object see this panel. There's a setting for Preview and Render resolution.

[image]

The SVG itself is also stretched in the width, internally it's showing a non-proportional viewbox property. Each coordinate is transformed according to the viewbox ratio.

```
viewBox="0 0 1 1.41379"
```

[image]

save it again from CorelDraw with proportional dimensions (can't help you with that) or edit the .svg manually (easy). Look for the line with `viewBox="0 0 1 1.41379"` and change it to `viewBox="0 0 1.41379 1.41379"`, or `"0 0 1 1"`

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. The default settings for SVG curve import are very low, it's a shame, I've had to redo a project because extruded fonts had flat planes visible on the "rounded" parts and I noticed after converting to mesh.