# Why the svg file imported not in scale

Tags: svg

I have made a svg file just a normal circle of 6.489 cm x 6.489 cm and made the svg file in coreldraw. As there are no option while making the svg file. And then i imported in blender i get 53.092 cm x 41.017 cm i didnt get a circular shape. And when importing in blender there is no option for any scale, etc. How can i import the similar geometry made. If u want to check my svg file... https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwiTD4qoMzsZcjdqdmNPVnlpTWc

Comment: probably related to the configuration of the svg exporter. very similar to the other svg scale question.. http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65656/why-does-the-shape-differ-when-importing-an-svg-file/65660#65660

Comment: coreldraw has plenty of export settings. read them carefully: http://unsolicitedbutoffered.blogspot.nl/2013/02/coreldraw-basics-exporting-to-svg-for.html

Comment: drag the svg from your filebrowser into the inner most rectangle on https://gist.github.com/ ,  choose 'create public gist' and copy the url it creates as a comment below.

Comment: @zeffi the similar question  u have given link is of my post few days ago and i did not get the answer to what i mean

Comment: if my answer there didn't help you should ask clarifcation as a comment to my answer.

Comment: @zeffi svg is attach u can download it from the link

Comment: the svg shows that the viewbox is not square `viewBox="0 0 1 1.29412">` , Blender's svg importer uses the Viewbox to proportion the svg's coordinates.  Show a picture of your CoralDraw's Document Properties during export..